# Showing more than one DataTable on same page (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, datatables

I am developing a Flask application, I have an HTML template in which I have two tables, for which I want to use the datatable plugin. Here is the code of my HTML template with the tables

```
<doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title> car_name </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='aesthetic.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_1').DataTable();
    $('#table_2').DataTable();
} );
</script>

<div class="spacebox"></div>

<div class="boxheader">

<a id="Shops">Shops</a>

</div>

<div id="bigbox">

<table id="table_1" border="1" style="background: white">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><b>Phosphosite ID</b></th>
<th><b>Protein</b></th>
<th ><b>Gene</b></th>
<th><b>Residue</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    {% for x in searchshops %}
<tr>
<td> {{x.NAME}} </td>
<td> {{x.RESOURCES}} </td>
<td> {{x.CARS}} </td>
<td> {{x.BRANDS}}</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}

</tbody>

</table>
</div>


<div class="spacebox"></div>

<div class="boxheader">

<a id="Cars">Cars</a>

</div>


<div class="bigbox">

<table id="table_2" border="1" style="background: white">


<tr>
<th><b>Name</b></th>
<th ><b>Shop</b></th>
</tr>

{% for x in searchcars %}
<tr>
<td> {{x.CAR}}</td>
<td> {{x.Shop}} </td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}


</table>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

(searchshops and searchcars are SQLAlchemy queries to a database, in my Flask python script)

The datatable attributes (search bar, sort columns), show on the first table but not the second one.

I have also tried the following script, (having added class="display" after both tables, based on this example https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html )

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

But I have the same problem.

How can I apply the datatable plugin to both tables?
Thank you.

Comment: first of all, you cant have 2 divs with same id. you have "spacebox","boxheader","bigbox" duplicated. Ids must be unique and used only once

Comment: That is not the part of the code that I have a problem with

Comment: Try adding thodu and thread in second table

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug that it only applies to the first table and not on the succeeding table/s regardless if the first table is initialized or not with DataTable. I've tried it, it's the same.
Maybe you can use this concept. The datatables were rendered serverside.

[multitable serverside rendering](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/services/two-datatables)